# Qt stylesheets: QHeaderView draws header text in bold when view data is selected

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I'm trying to style a QTableView with Qt Stylesheets. Everything works OK, except that all the table header texts (column headers) are drawn as bold text whenever data in the table view is selected.

I've tried things like this:

```
QTableView::section {
    font-weight: 400;
}
QTableView::section:selected {
    font-weight: 400;
}

QHeaderView {
    font-weight: 400;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, ideally using stylesheets?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but setting the [QHeaderView::highlightSections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#highlightSections-prop) property to false should do the trick.

You can get a pointer to a QHeaderView object using QTableView's `verticalHeader()` and `horizontalHeader()` methods.

Comment: Brilliant! Why didn't I see that!? Thanks! Interesting that according to the docs the default value for that property should be false...

Answer (score 0):

In Qt Designer UI format you can use the attribute `horizontalHeaderHighlightSections`:

```
 <widget class="QTableView" name="m_studyList">
  <attribute name="horizontalHeaderHighlightSections">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </attribute>
```

But it also completely disables css for selected columns.